# Remove anything between () except for ; in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

A simple question but I can't find the answer.
I'm scanning a huge pile of mails and  would like to get rid of anything between () in the email adresses since this normally contains just info that varies over time.
As a delimiter I use the ; between the email addresses.
So this is basically the only character not allowed between ().

```
tst = "James, Jekyll (The.nice.guy@gmails.com \n); Hannibal, Hyde (from@hell ...)"
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

```
StringReplace[tst, "(" ~~ __ ... ~~ ")" -> ""]
```

It only leaves me James, Jekyll

So I assume I need a pattern like "("~~Anything Except ";"~~")" but how?

```
StringReplace[tst,"(" ~~ (DigitCharacter|WordCharacter|WhitespaceCharacter|"@"|"!"|".") ... ~~ ")" -> ""]
```

Will work but then to be safe I would need to get all characters in the ( | | etc)
construct at seams unefficient.

Any thougths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention the delimiter `;`, I assume you want to do *two* things: remove the parentheses *and* split the string up into separate names.

```
StringTrim@
 StringSplit[StringReplace[tst, "(" ~~ Except[")"|";"] ... ~~ ")" -> ""], 
  ";"]
```

This uses another version of `StringReplace` similar to Mr. Wizard's but not using `Shortest`. The `StringSplit` is what uses `;` to identify separate email names.

The `StringTrim` is only added here to remove white space.

From the fact that you accepted Mr.Wizard's answer I understand that you wish for the replacement to fail when there is a `;` between the `( ...)`. I've "upgraded" my solution to satisfy this strange requirement.

Comment: that is a nice way to represent Shortest!

Comment: It is also more flexible than using shortest.

Comment: Yes it is a strange requirement. But I found a very limited use (2 out of 441 addresses) of the ; sign to denote an email address Like Me, To (strange@mail; blah blah). Perhaps I should just ignore these mail addresses but they do occur also in other mails so to correlate them.. Perhaps it's to far fetched.. Thx

Answer (score 4):

This will do what you want (concerning your original problem, not involving `;`):

```
StringReplace[tst, ShortestMatch["(" ~~ __  ~~ ")"] -> ""]
```

The default is `LongestMatch`, which is why you did not get the rest.

Comment: "As of Version 6.0, `ShortestMatch` has been superseded by the pattern object `Shortest`." :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is this true for strings as well?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is.  Isn't that the new paradigm?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Somehow I always felt that `ShortestMatch` is for strings only, and works differently (and most likely much faster) than `Shortest` for patterns, because string patterns are generally much faster than Mathematica patterns when used in string-processing built-in functions.

Comment: I believe it is just internally overloaded; if used for strings it switches.  I only performed one test but I'm not seeing an efficiency difference.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you are probably right. I just did not know about it.

Comment: Leonid, I just posted a Q/A hoping to address some of the basic question regarding *Mathematica* string patterns.  I'd appreciate you taking a look at it and telling me where it needs improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Still

```
StringReplace[tst, "(" ~~ Shortest@x__ ~~ ")" -> ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After some consideration I do need `Shortest` as Leonid indicates:

```
StringReplace[tst, Shortest["(" ~~ Except[";"] ... ~~ ")"] -> ""]
```

Comment: I would suspect that when I use a ; in between the brackets the result would be different but it isn't.

Comment: No it's fine.. took the wrong string to test on.. sigh.. Since your answer matches most closely the question I'll accept your answer.